# AVD Android Emulator freezes on run

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm a n00b trying to get the HelloWord application from the Google developer example up and running.  I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 w/ the latest Android SDK and ADT. I've got through the whole thing up until the running of the application where the emulator loads, but just freezes w/ a blank screen.  The window it's in becomes unresponsive and I end up having to sudo kill the process to get rid of it.

I've read around and heard that it can take 10 min or so to load up the first time, but I've gone ahead and let it sit there for much longer, only to have nothing to show for it.

Anyone out there have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initialising your emulator, maybe you can try with another emulator,, make click on Window--> AVD manager. click on new create on and put start selecting the one you created, also you should verify that you have Java installed on your computer.
Nut maybe you can explain all the thing you did to set up your environment so we can check a possible error, I have Eclipse 3.7.1 with the latest Amndroid SDK running perfectly on my Ubuntu 11.10